# How to resolve an identification issue when publishing a Microsoft Edge extension?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I have made appx file, i have tested on Windows App Certification Kit Toolkit and also installing extension in windows 10 running properly, but when I publish the extension to the Store, it gives me this error:

```
"App Policies: 10.1.1 Extensions
```

> Notes To Developer
>
> Apps that claim to be an extension must clearly identify the app for
>   which they are an extension"

I have given a description in the json and appx files and also in windows dev partner, but it's still giving the same error in certification.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your extension is violating the policy 10.1.1.

As per the Microsoft below is the policy 10.1.1:

> All aspects of your app should accurately describe the functions, features and any important limitations of your app, including required or supported input devices. Your app may not use a name or icon similar to that of other apps, and may not claim to be from a company, government body, or other entity if you do not have permission to make that representation.
>
> Reference: [Microsoft Store Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/windows/agreements/store-policies)

So you can try to refer to to the policy and check what thing in your extension cause this error.

Try to modify that thing and create a new package and try to host again may help you to solve the issue.

Comment: Yes i have already seen this store policies and changed file accordingly but still having problem

Comment: @  QTechnolog Sol , I will try to find the more possible causes for this error and will inform you about that. It may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: Further I want to confirm with you that do you still get the same error message or the error message is changed now? If there is a new error message then try to let us know about the latest error message. It can help us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Yes i have done some changes in xml file but error increasing..now only error which is not solving is above that i have describe

Comment: You can try to check whether you are using any names or functions that are already used by someone else that you are not aware about or you are using any image that is not allowed to used. removing that may help to solve this error.